# Lost perspective when applying CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, perspective

I am trying to apply CSS3 transforms to some HTML elements and noticed that whenever I tried to apply keyframe animations to element, the `perspective` goes off.

I am putting two screens, one before animation is added (1) and other after animation is added (2).

**Before animation is added:**

```css
ul {
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  -moz-perspective: 300px;
  -o-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  transform: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #666;
  z-index: 2
}
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #666;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[Demo - Before animation is added](https://jsfiddle.net/t149q8Lq/)

**After animation is added:**

```css
ul {
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  -moz-perspective: 300px;
  -o-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #666;
  z-index: 2
}
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #666;
  width: 200px;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-animation: wing1 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: wing1 1s infinite;
  -o-animation: wing1 1s infinite;
  animation: wing1 1s infinite;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-animation: wing2 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: wing2 1s infinite;
  -o-animation: wing2 1s infinite;
  animation: wing2 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes wing1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wing2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes wing1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes wing2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes wing1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes wing2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
}
@keyframes wing1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
}
@keyframes wing2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[Demo - After animation is added](https://jsfiddle.net/mr7Lkfqe/1/)

What might be wrong here? Any one please suggest.

Comment: Any idea, how can i accomplish it with pure css3?

Comment: Like a wing flap in Fiddle 1 without any visual change.... What might be wrong with my css....?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mr7Lkfqe/2/) what you need? (Note this has only webkit specific prefixes).

Comment: nope, just 90 degree turn....Need a bird wing flip type... :)

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr7Lkfqe/3/). See the gif animation...but that is top view...But one posted is rotated perspective, but wing flip should be that way...

Comment: One extra thing that you should probably note. You put in effort to create two fiddles which explain your problem which is great but don't format the fiddle link as code block. Instead use the `<>` (snippet) toolbar icon to insert the code into the question itself. Formatting fiddle link as code block is frowned upon and likely to get you downvotes in future. I have made the changes for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you were seeing was not because of the perspective being lost or not getting applied but actually because your original transform was getting over-written by the values specified within the animation's keyframes.

Originally the element (without animation) is rotated in the X axis by 60 degree using `rotate3d()` but when the animation is added, the only transform that is specified within the `keyframes` is a rotate in Y axis. As is the case with any CSS property, a subsequent setting is not additive to the original setting but it actually overwrites it and so when the animation is applied, the rotation in  X axis is nullified.

To overcome this, the `transform` property within the `keyframes` should be modified such that the X axis rotation is kept constant throughout the animation while the Y axis rotate alone changes with the frames to produce a wing-flap like animation.

Below snippet should be what you need.

```css
ul {
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 300px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #666;
  z-index: 2
}
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #666;
  width: 200px;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: right center;
  animation: wing1 1s infinite;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: wing2 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes wing1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -60deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -60deg);
  }
}
@keyframes wing2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```